# mysql slow when CPU and memory are free

Tags: mysql, database, innodb, database-administration, my.cnf

I'm running some heavy mysql jobs `(mysql 5.1.67)` on a high performance machine `(EC2/c3.8xlarge)`.

the queries are really slow while `CPU usage` is under `1%` and `memory usage` is under `5%`.

**How can I let MySQL to use more resources? Is that possible?**

Comment: Could you include the query you are using?

Comment: And the my.cnf file your using

Comment: @sparkup the queries are very different. mostly indexing large tables. so the queries are heavy

Comment: @user1281385 max_connections = 201
max_heap_table_size=5120M
tmp_table_size=5120M
join_buffer_size=80M
query_cache_size=5240M
thread_cache_size=8
table_open_cache=1024
key_buffer_size=4024M

Comment: Is this an InnoDB table? Where are your InnoDB configuration options (e.g. `innodb_buffer_pool_size`)? Also please add this additional info the question, not only in an answer to a comment.